# Chain rule of 1-complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

Assuming $h(z)$ and $g(z)$ are differential complex functions, and $h$ is also differentiable at $g(z)$, to prove the chain rule:
$$(h(g(z)))'=h'(g(z))g'(z)$$

Here's my proof:

Since $g$ is differentiable, we have $g(z+t)=g(z)+g'(z)t+o(t^2)$, this identity comes from $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(z+t)-g(z)}{t}=g'(z)$.

Then for $h(g(z))$, we too have $h(g(z)+g'(z)t+o(t^2))=h(g(z))+h'(g(z))[g'(z)t+o(t^2)]+o([g'(z)t+o(t^2)]^2)$. And since $o([g'(z)t+o(t^2)]^2)=o(t^2)$, we can rewrite it as $h(g(z)+g'(z)t+o(t^2))=h(g(z))+h'(g(z))g'(z)t+o(t^2)$，

Then by differentiablity, $$
\begin{split}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(g(z+t))-h(g(z))}{t} & =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{h(g(z))+h'(g(z))g'(z)t+o(t^2)-h(g(z))}{t}\\
& =\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{h'(g(z))g'(z)t+o(t^2)}{t}\\
&=h'(g(z))g'(z)
\end{split}
$$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: the $o(t^2)$ should be $o(t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct but as zhw said, the $o(t^2)$ should be a $o(t)$.

You also don't need the last lines. By definition the differential of $f$ at $z$, $f'(z)$, (if it exists) is the unique linear application $\ell$ such that $f(z+t) = f(z) + \ell(t) + o(t)$. Thus the identity $h(g(z+t)) = h(g(z)) + g'(z)h(g(z))t + o(t)$ is enough for deduce $(h \circ g)'(z) =  g'(z)h(g(z))$.